# How to get MAX Values using the Having Clause in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a Column(Fields) that contain multiple values for each entity (One to Many).

Example: A record can can reference multiple values in this column.

What I want to do is get only records where highest(MAX) value in this column is equals zero.

The first thing I did was convert the values in the column to Integer, this way I can get the Max Value.

Here is my Code:

How do I get the Max code? If a record has more than one code. I want only record with the Max or highest code of 00000.

I am getting an error with the Having clause since I cannot use Aggregate in the Where Clause.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.USER_ID, MAX(CInt(CUSTOMER.REC_CODE)) AS ACTIVE_REC_CODE, 
CUSTOMER.CUS_TYPE


FROM CUSTOMER


WHERE ((CUSTOMER.REC_CODE) IS NOT NULL )


GROUP BY

CUSTOMER.USER_ID, CUSTOMER.REC_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_TYPE


HAVING  MAX(CInt([CUSTOMER.REC_CODE])= 00000 )
```

Comment: I am confused, why is the existing select Max not suitable for you?

Comment: Because I am not sure the result set from the query is accurate.

Comment: You say  00000, 11111, 22222, 33333, but 00000 is MIN of this list. Do you want MAX or MIN?

Comment: Additional info: Basically I am trying to get records with codes = 00000. The problem is, some records can have both 00000, 11111 and so on. So in simpliest terms, I want only record that code = 00000 and nothing else.

Comment: So why not `Select * From Customers Where Rec_Code=0`  or `"0000"` if it is text?

Comment: Again what about records that have multiple REC_CODES? Example: Wont that also return records with REC_CODE = 00000, 111111?
I do not want Records with multiple codes, only records with one code. It's a one to many relationship.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6862/discussion-between-remou-and-unaverage-guy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, but you need to remove `CUSTOMER.REC_CODE` from your `WHERE`, since you want the max value of that column. This should work:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.USER_ID, MAX(CInt(CUSTOMER.REC_CODE)) AS ACTIVE_REC_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_TYPE
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER.REC_CODE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.USER_ID, CUSTOMER.CUS_TYPE
HAVING  MAX(CInt([CUSTOMER.REC_CODE])) = 0
```

Comment: I tried this and I am not sure it is working. Just to make sure, I would like to asked: What if a record has REC_CODE as follows: 00000, 11111, 22222, 33333 and another REC_CODE has only 00000 Will the query above give me both record, or only the second record?

Comment: I think you are confused as what you want. The query I wrote will return all of the `USER_ID` and `CUS_TYPE` that have a maximum `REC_CODE` of 00000.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy: This query will only return the second row for your example. Basically, if you do not have NULLs in `REC_CODE` nor values that evaluate to negative integers, this solution should be enough for you (I think).